# How to remap mqtt value to some other topics in mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have a value under `milight/states/0x1/fut089/1`.

What I'm trying to do is to replicate this to `milight/states/0x[2..4]/fut089/1`

[image: Description of the mqtt structure]

I've already tried the following config:

```
connection milight-forwarder
address localhost:1883
cleansession true
topic # out 0 milight/states/0x1/ milight/states/0x2/
topic # out 0 milight/states/0x1/ milight/states/0x3/
topic # out 0 milight/states/0x1/ milight/states/0x4/
```

The first one seems to work somehow but it replicates all of the values (1,2,4).
If I append a 1 to the source and the destination mosquitto throws these errors:

```
1591289258: Connecting bridge (step 1) milight-forwarder (localhost:1883)
1591289258: Connecting bridge (step 2) milight-forwarder (localhost:1883)
1591289258: New connection from ::1 on port 1883.
1591289258: New bridge connected from ::1 as RasPi.milight-forwarder (p2, c1, k60).
1591289258: Invalid unsubscription string from RasPi.milight-forwarder, disconnecting.
1591289258: Socket error on client RasPi.milight-forwarder, disconnecting.
1591289258: Socket error on client local.RasPi.milight-forwarder, disconnecting.
```

I'm using mosquitto version 1.6.8.

[Documentation](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) wasn't helpful to me :/

Any help here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the unsubscribe error, but I do get the same effect of only the first mapping taking effect.

Without digging into the code I'm going to assume that the bridge is stopping at the first matching pattern, which in this case is `#` which matches everything.

This makes sense, especially when we remember that loopback bridging to the same broker is really just a nasty hack.

I'm using 1.6.8 on Ubuntu rather than raspbian but it should be the same.

Comment: So how can I change the maching pattern that it does apply correctly?

Comment: You are going to have write a small app that does the republishing